# Query causing load because of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS post counting?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, wpdb

I found this query causing some load in the server, my hosting provdier asked me to look on it.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts
```

I think this select no. rows found in wp_posts table.. but i tried to this query in separate page, it takes so long to complete the request.Can somebody help me to overcome from this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

WordPress uses this feature of MySQL to get a total count of posts when you are only retrieving limited amount (100 posts total, but only 10 posts per page).

From quick look at source there is `no_found_rows` query argument that can disable it. That will wreck pagination and should only be used with specific queries that don't *need* counting (for example [`get_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_posts/) uses it by default).

You probably need to look into performance of your database overall (if you are running something crazy large) or if there are issues with configuration (if you are running something small enough to not possibly cause issues with resources).

Comment: as you said, if it is used only for pagination means, can i query manually. something like  "select count(*) from wp_posts"? doest it affects pagination and others contents?

Comment: @Sekar there is no guarantee that separate query would be any faster (it depends on database setup and I am not sure how would WP's database behave) and it sure would be huge pain to cleanly change from one to another. As per my answer I'd start looking into why it is slow instead of trying to get rid of it without insight into what is going on.