# How to disable `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`

Tags: mysql, core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wordpress query causing load](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/wordpress-query-causing-load)

In the site I'm trying to optimize, I noticed several queries that are rather slow and start with **`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`**

Searching this site, the relevant question **[wordpress query causing load](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/wordpress-query-causing-load)** has no adequate answer, in my opinion.

Can I somehow disable `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` without breaking too many things - if possible breaking nothing? It seems that pagination relies on this.

@Wyck advised me to read this core ticket: **[#10964](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10964)**. After reading it, I can't really understand if the ticket been completely resolved, it seems not.

In any case, is there a way to disable `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First should only disable `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` if you aren't using pagination, to do so set parameter `no_found_rows` to `true` in WP_Query.

```
WP_Query( array( 'no_found_rows' => true ) );
```

**Note** `get_posts()` does that by default.